# How to reload card in react on data submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I want to display the card when I submit data for the card. But I have to refresh the page to see changes I want to auto-refresh that card component on submitting data.
I have used use effect for that but still, it's not working. The value becoming true but data is not displayed. Still, I have to refresh the page. How can i solve this issue?

[image]

```
import { TextField, Box, Typography, Button, Link, DialogContent, CircularProgress, Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContentText, DialogActions } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Cards from 'react-credit-cards';
import 'react-credit-cards/es/styles-compiled.css';
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { CardData } from '../../services/user-controller';
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import { addCard, cardDelete, getCardList } from '../../services/card-controller';
import { ApplicationContext } from '../../context/applicationCtx';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import CancelIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Cancel';
import styles from "./mystyle.module.css"
import loadCardList from "../../pages/auth/main-app.js"
export default function PaymentForm() {

  const {
    getCardsList_CTX, setCardList_CTX, getReloadModuleData, setReloadModuleData
  } = useContext(ApplicationContext);

  
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [getLoaderState, setLoaderState] = useState(false);
  const [cardClick, setCardClick] = useState(false);
  const [cardNumber, setCardNumber] = useState('');
  const [cardName, setCardName] = useState('');
  const [cardExpiry, setCardExpiry] = useState('');
  const [cardCvv, setCardCvv] = useState('');
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState('');
  const [cardId, setCardId] = useState('');
  // const [inpval, setInpval] = useState('');
  const [cardn, setCardn] = useState('');
  const [carde, setCarde] = useState('');

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [deleteCard, setDeleteCard] = useState(null);
  const [reloadData,setReloadData] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = (card) => {
    setOpen(true);
    setDeleteCard(card)
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleDeleteCard = async function (){
    let cardNum = `000000000000${deleteCard.cardNo.substring(4,8)}`

    try {

      setLoaderState(true);

      let response = await cardDelete({
        "cardNo": cardNum,
        "expiryMonth": deleteCard.expiryMonth,
        "expiryYear": deleteCard.expiryYear
      })
      if(response.status === 200 || response.status === 202 ){
        setLoaderState(false);
        setOpen(false)
        
      }

    } catch (err) {
      setLoaderState(false);
      if (err.data) {

        //TODO:: ADD ERROR MESSAGES setStepLicenseKey({ ...getStepLicenseKey, errorMsg: err.data.message, hasError: true });
      }else {
        if (err.errorMsg) {
          // setStepLicenseKey(err)
          console.log(err.errorMsg)
        } else {
          console.error("UNKNOWN ERROR", err);
          
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const handleChange = prop => (e) => {

    switch (prop) {
      case 'cardNumber':
        setCardNumber(e.target.value)
        break;
      case 'cardName':
        setCardName(e.target.value)
        break;
      case 'cardExpiry':
        setCardExpiry(e.target.value)
        break;
      case 'cardCvv':
        setCardCvv(e.target.value)
        break;
      case 'cardId':
        setCardId(e.target.value)
        break;
        default:
          break;
    }

  }

  const handleInputFocus = (e) => {
    setFocus( e.target.name );
  }
    
  const handleCardClick = (cardDetail, i) => {
    setCardClick(true)
  }

  const delCancel = () => {
    setCardClick(false)
  }
    

  const verifyInputs = async function () {
    try {

      setLoaderState(true);
      const month = cardExpiry.substring(0, 2);
      const year = `20${cardExpiry.substring(2)}`;
   
      let response = await addCard({
        "cardHolderName": cardName,
        "cardNo": cardNumber,
        "cvv": cardCvv,
        "expiryMonth": month,
        "expiryYear": year,
        "cardId": cardNumber
      })
      if(response.status === StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST){
      setError(response.data.message)
      
      }
     
     
    // console.log(response,'rt')

     else if (response.status === StatusCodes.OK) {
      console.log(response)
      setLoaderState(false)
      setReloadData(true)
      
      loadCardList();
      } else {
        setLoaderState(false)
       
        throw (response);
      }


    } catch (err) {
      setLoaderState(false);
      
      if (err.data) {

        //TODO:: ADD ERROR MESSAGES setStepLicenseKey({ ...getStepLicenseKey, errorMsg: err.data.message, hasError: true });
      }
      else {
        if (err.errorMsg) {
          // setStepLicenseKey(err)
          console.log(err.errorMsg)
        } else {
          console.error("UNKNOWN ERROR", err);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  // console.log(getCardsList_CTX,'yy')
 useEffect(()=>{

   if(reloadData == true){
    getCardList();


  }
console.log(reloadData)

 },[reloadData])
 

  return (


    <>


      <Box display="flex" sx={{
        "width":"1459px","height":"44px","backgroundColor":"#F9FAFA","position":"relative","top":"0px",left:'77px',
      }}></Box>
        {/* TODO ADD CARDS HERE */}
       
        <Box display="flex" sx={{
        "width":"621px","height":"192px","position":"relative","top":"121px",left:'99px',gap:'10px'
        }}>
        {getCardsList_CTX.map((card, index)=>{

          return (
            
            <Box width="292px"  height="184px" className={styles.card} onClick={() => handleCardClick(card, index)}>
              {/* <CancelIcon color="error" sx={{ zIndex: 1, position: 'relative', left: '74%', top: '1%' }} /> */}
              <Cards
                key={nanoid()}
                cvc={card.cvv}
                expiry={`${card.expiryMonth < 9 ? '0' + card.expiryMonth : card.expiryMonth}${card.expiryYear.toString().substring(2)}`}
                name={card.cardHolderName}
                number={`000000000000${card.cardNo.substring(4)}`}
                issuer={'visa'}
                preview={true}
              />
              {/* <Box position="absolute" width="100%" minHeight="100%" maxHeight="100%" bgcolor="red" zIndex='1'>

              </Box> */}
              <Box position="absolute" zIndex='2' onClick={() => {handleClickOpen(card)}}>
                <CancelIcon  sx={{ zIndex: 1,"position":"absolute","left":"263px","top":"-180px",color:"#dbd4d4",cursor:'pointer'  }} />
              </Box>
            </Box>
          )
      }) }
      </Box>

      

      

      <Box sx={{ "width": "1536px", "height": "1px", "backgroundColor": "#ece5e5", "position": "absolute", "top": "385px" }}></Box>

      <Typography mt={5} variant="h3" component="h2" sx={{ "position": "absolute", "top": "24px", "fontSize": "29px", "left": "97px" }}>
        PAYMENT METHOD
      </Typography>

      <Typography mt={5} variant="h3" component="h2" sx={{ "position": "absolute", "top": "69px", "fontSize": "24px", "left": "108px", color: '#9C9C9C' }}>
        YOUR SAVED CARDS
      </Typography>

      <Box style={{ "position": "absolute", "display": "flex", "top": "431px", "left": "418px" }} id="PaymentForm">

        <Typography mt={5} variant="h3" component="h2" sx={{ whiteSpace:'nowrap', "position": "absolute", "top": "-79px", "fontSize": "20px", "left": "307px", color: '#9C9C9C' }}>
          ENTER CARD DETAILS - SAVE/DELETE
        </Typography>
        <Cards
          cvc={cardCvv}
          expiry={cardExpiry}
          focused={focus}
          name={cardName}
          number={cardNumber}
          sx={{ "marginRight": "12px" }}
        />
        <form style={{ width: '333px', marginLeft: '18px' }}>

          <TextField type="tel"
            name="number"
            placeholder="Card Number"
            onChange={handleChange('cardNumber')}
            onFocus={handleInputFocus} id="outlined-basic" label="Card Number" variant="outlined"
            sx={{ width: '340px' }}
            inputProps={{ maxLength: 16 }}
            
            
          />

            <TextField
              type="tel"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Name"
              onChange={handleChange('cardName')}
              onFocus={handleInputFocus}
              id="outlined-basic" label="Card Holder" variant="outlined"
              sx={{ "marginTop": "12px", width: '340px' }}
            />
  
         <Box sx={{ "display": "flex", "marginTop": "12px", width: '359px' }}>
            <TextField
              type="tel"
              name="expiry"
              placeholder="Expiry"
              onChange={handleChange('cardExpiry')}
              onFocus={handleInputFocus}
              id="outlined-basic" label="Expiry" variant="outlined"
              sx={{ "display": "flex", marginRight: '16px', width: '340px' }}
              inputProps={{ maxLength: 4 }}

            />

              <TextField

                type="tel"
                name="cvc"
                placeholder="CVV"
                onChange={handleChange('cardCvv')}
                onFocus={handleInputFocus}
                id="outlined-basic" label="CVV" variant="outlined"
                inputProps={{ maxLength: 3 }}
                sx={{ marginRight: '19px' }}
              />        
          </Box>
        </form>
        <Typography mt={5} variant="h3" component="h2" sx={{ whiteSpace:'nowrap', "position": "absolute", "top": "160px", "fontSize": "10px", "left": "312px", color: 'red',textTransform:'uppercase',fontWeight: 'bold',letterSpacing:'2px' }}>
         {error}
        </Typography>

        <Button disabled={getLoaderState} onClick={verifyInputs}  variant="contained" disableElevation sx={{  mt: 1, pr: 2 ,"marginTop":"219px","width":"159px","height":"43px","marginLeft":"-241px"}} >
          Save Card {getLoaderState ? <CircularProgress size="1.2em" sx={{ "position": "absolute", right: "0", mr: 2 }} /> : ""}
        </Button>

{/* Payment Card Delete */}
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
          {"Delete Payment Card"}
        </DialogTitle> 
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Are you sure you want to delete your card({deleteCard !== null ? deleteCard.cardNo : ''}), you can't retrive it later on.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} sx={{ color: 'red' }}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleDeleteCard}>
            Proceed
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      </Box>

      

    </>

  );
}
```

Comment: Following you structure, you need to add the useEffect in your ApplicationContext, and make everytime reloadData has changed, refresh getCardsList_CTX.
Because you are using getCardsList_CTX to serve your data, so that data need to know when to be refreshed.

Comment: Have you tried moving the useeffect on top of functional component ?

Comment: yes, still not working

Comment: Anyone can tell the exact solution for that. I am still do not understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the context that the content has updated. As for React Contact api you would need to change the state of the provider.

Here is an article that shows how to use the context api.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: Hi I am still not able to understand Can you please help once. Thanks

Comment: ok cool, let me code it down.

Comment: sure please help me I got stuck here and am not able to understand what's happening.

Comment: can you please help me solve this. It's urgent.

Comment: sorry, on it now

Comment: https://github.com/DrDouble/CardAdder

Comment: Here this is the example of how you can use context api to add cards to your state. Just run the app and you can add cards. However, you would need to adapt to your code.

Comment: @AnkitKumar have you checked the repo?

Comment: Hi, I understand your code well. But not understand how to do refresh when we are sending and getting data from an API. Can you please check the above code and tell me what can be the solution for that.